# addlistener focus react native only works on second refresh react-native

Tags: react-native, addeventlistener, setstate, react-navigation-v5

so I've been trying to reload the content from asyncStorage in a screen when navigating back from a second screen, but it only refreshes when i navigate forth and back again

here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
        const {navigation} = this.props
        navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
           
            AsyncStorage.getItem('Servers').then((servers) => {
                servers = JSON.parse(servers);
                if (servers) {
                    return this.setState({servers:servers, loaded: true})

                }
                this.setState({servers: [], loaded: true});

            });
            
        });

    };
```

Also, i think it should be re-rendering everytime a setState is done, but its not doing it for some reason

Comment: That's the expected behavior ... cause you've only registered a listener for focus event .... Execute the callback of `addListener` directly in componentDidMount ...

Comment: like componentDidMount().addListener('focus',()=>{... ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior ... cause you've only registered a listener for focus event .... Execute the callback of addListener directly in componentDidMount...

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  
  yourFocusHandler();
  this.unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', yourFocusHandler);

};

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code after the changes:

```
focusHandler(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('Servers').then((servers) => {
            servers = JSON.parse(servers);
            if (servers.length) {
                return this.setState({servers, carregado: true})
            }

            this.setState({carregado: true});

        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {navigation} = this.props
        this.focusHandler();
        navigation.addListener('focus', this.focusHandler());

    };
```

it gives the following error:
[image]

Comment: and this one:  Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: It's better to update your question with the issues you have :) .... and the issue you have because you need to cancel subscription in `componentWillUnmount` ...  checkout the edit in my answer...

Comment: ++ pass the handler **not  a call to the handler** ... `navigation.addListener('focus', this.focusHandler);`